# Time Interval in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm working on an app and in that, I want to display different views on different times of day (e.g. `View1()` from 12:00 PM to : 3:00PM and `View2()` from 3:00 PM to 8:00 PM)

Edit: The problem here is, that when its 15:30, `View1()` will be opened instead of `View3()`.

```
let dateComps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: Date())

struct MainView: View{

var body: some View{

if (dateComps.hour! >= 12 && dateComps.minute! >= 30) && dateComps.hour! <= 15 {
   View1()
} else if dateComps.hour! >= 15 && (dateComps.hour! <= 18 && dateComps.minute! <= 30) {

   View2()

} else {

   View3()
}

}

}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview

Comment: Do you want to switch views while they are opened or decide which view to open based on the time?

Comment: decide based on time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the view based on the time of day, you could try using something like [DateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponents). The code for such a system is below (works with IOS 15/ Xcode 13)

```swift
//You can use anything in the brackets,such as weekday,
let dateComps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .day, .weekday, .month], from: Date())

struct MainView: View{

    var body: some View {
        //24 Hour format, measured in ints 
        if dateComps.hour! <= 12 { 

        //If morning
        morningView()

        } else if dateComps.hour! <= 18 {

            //afternoon
            afternoonView()

        } else {

            //Other or Evening view
            eveningView()
        }
    }
}
```

You could also switch this stuff in a function and return a variable or something based on the time of day. Just make sure you put the thing you want from the components after the overall components name, and unwrap it - use ! or ? if you want to provide a default value.

Comment: Thanks! One final thing I want to know is how to define hours with minutes (e.g. 15:30)

Comment: @JackSparrow567 though you can't do hours as floats (such as 15.5), you could also put in .minute into the brackets and then check for the minute too. This would be something like if dateComps.hour <=12 && dateComps.minute <= 30.

Comment: I updated the code at the top, there is still an issue with that suggestion you gave.

Comment: What is the issue? Are you making sure to unwrap the minute? If so, try taking away the and and instead putting it inside the first if like this:  if dateComps.hour! <= 12{if dateComps.minute! <=30{      }}